# How can I find a single user in Active Directory by common name using PrincipalSearcher?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm trying to use System.DirectoryServices to find the manager of a user. So I use the current code to get the manager.

```
 string test = string.Empty;
 using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
 {
   using(var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "user"))
   {                    
     DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
     test = de.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
   }
 }
```

The test variable then contains only the CN or common name of the manager. I need to use that common name to get the actual user of the manager. Because I need things like UserID and Email etc.. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: The `manager` field contains _distinguished_ names, not _common_ names. `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, test)` should do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`manager` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-manager) contains the distinguished name of the manager's account (the common name is just the `CN=` portion of the distinguished name).

You can use [`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbyidentity) with that distinguished name, just like you did with the user:

```
var manager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, test);
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I didn't realize. Thank you.